# Как при старте бота чистить все сообщения, которые были до его запуска

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

При запуске бота мне нужно очищать чат. Может как-то можно удалить чат и потом прислать сообщение, или при команде старт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на вопрос. При отправке любого сообщения, заношу его message_id в словарь, ключ - id пользователя, значение - список со всеми айдишниками. Потом при вызове какой-либо команды циклом пробегаю по массиву попутно удаляя все сообщения, которые я туда записывал. После процесса удаляю массив и по новой.

Comment: имейте ввиду, что можно удалить сообщения не старше 48 часов